# OpenID on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, openid, privacy

Is OpenID on Stack Overflow private, or can other users tell what email address posted the question?

Comment: Note that OpenID and e-mail address aren't the same, they're separate fields in your profile. Both are private

Answer (score 5):

email address is private, not shown

Comment: Thanks.  I guess it is only showing when I'm logged in I was just curious.